# Object categories of pretrained imagenet model in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, matcaffe

I'm using the pretrained imagenet model provided along the caffe (CNN) library (`'bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'`). I can output a 1000 dim vector of object scores for any images using this model.
However I don't know what the actual object categories are. Did someone find a file, where the corresponding object categories are listed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look for the file `'synset_words.txt'` it has 1000 line each line provides a description of a different class.

For more information on how to get this file (and some others you might need) you can read [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html).

---

If you want all the labels to be ready-for-use in Matlab, you can read the txt file into a cell array (a cell per class):

```
C = textread('/path/to/synset_words.txt','%s','delimiter','\n');
```

Comment: That's it, thanks :). By the way. Did you figure out a best way to read this text file automatically? In Matlab would do "fopen(file)" and then "textscan". But in that case the number of columns has to be fixed (which isn't the case for 'sysnem_words').